# Sitecore XMC Breadcrumb

Tags: next.js, sitecore

What's the best way to create a breadcrumb for pages in Sitecore NextJS, XMC?
I thought of graphql, but then the author cannot view the breadcrumb until it is published to the Edge.
The Pages Navigation has  a breadcrumb option, which doesn't really do much.

Is there any other way to do this?